# How to separate variables in an email button in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, email, xamarin

I have a button for sending e-mails, it uses some variables from the app like RadioGroups and a EditText field.

I want to send on the email body the radiobuttons on the first paragraph and the EditText comment on the second paragraph.

**My question is: how can I separate them to automatically the buttons go on the first paragrah and the EditText variable that is nammed as comentario goes on the second paragraph, just like if the user "clicked on the enter button"
Should I use something like &nbsp if so, how do I do it?**

```
void enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        RadioButton rdbgrupo1 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgconquiste.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                        RadioButton rdbgrupo2 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgcrie.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                        RadioButton rdbgrupo3 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgviva.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                        RadioButton rdbgrupo4 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgentregue.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                    int RadioGroupIsChecked(RadioGroup radioGroup)
                    {
                        //-1 means empty selection
                        return radioGroup.CheckedRadioButtonId;
                    }

                    //When user doesn't check a radio button, show a Toast
                    if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) == -1)
                    {
                        string excecao = "Ao menos um botão de cada campo deve ser selecionado e o comentário deve ser preenchido";
                        Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String emailescolhido = spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
                        String campocomentario = comentário.Text;

                        var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
                        //send to
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail,
                        new string[] { "" + emailescolhido });
                        //cc to
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc,
                        new string[] { "" });
                        //subject
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "SABIA QUE VOCÊ FOI RECONHECIDO?");
                        //content
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                        "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "&nbsp" + campocomentario);
                        email.SetType("message/rfc822");
                        StartActivity(email);
                        Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        alertdialog.SetTitle("Confirmação de envio");
                        alertdialog.SetMessage("Email enviado com sucesso");
                        alertdialog.SetNeutralButton("Ok", delegate {
                            alertdialog.Dispose();
                        });
                        alertdialog.Show();
                    }


                }


                catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
                {
                    showbox(ex.Message);

                } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using System.Environment.NewLine

```
void enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    RadioButton rdbgrupo1 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgconquiste.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                    RadioButton rdbgrupo2 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgcrie.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                    RadioButton rdbgrupo3 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgviva.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                    RadioButton rdbgrupo4 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgentregue.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                    int RadioGroupIsChecked(RadioGroup radioGroup)
                    {
                        //-1 means empty selection
                        return radioGroup.CheckedRadioButtonId;
                    }

                    //When user doesn't check a radio button, show a Toast
                    if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) == -1)
                    {
                        string excecao = "Ao menos um botão de cada campo deve ser selecionado e o comentário deve ser preenchido";
                        Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String emailescolhido = spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();

                        if (emailescolhido == "Escolha um colaborador abaixo")
                        {
                            string excecao = "Por favor, escolha um colaborador";
                            Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();

                        }

                        else { 
                        String campocomentario = comentário.Text;

                        var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
                        //send to
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail,
                        new string[] { "" + emailescolhido });
                        //cc to
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc,
                        new string[] { "" });
                        //subject
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "SABIA QUE VOCÊ FOI RECONHECIDO?");
                        //content
                        email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                        "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        email.SetType("message/rfc822");
                        StartActivity(email);
                        Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        alertdialog.SetTitle("Confirmação de envio");
                        alertdialog.SetMessage("Email enviado com sucesso");
                        alertdialog.SetNeutralButton("Ok", delegate {
                            alertdialog.Dispose();
                        });
                        alertdialog.Show();
                    }
                    }


                }


                catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
                {
                    showbox(ex.Message);

                } } }
```